# Cropping image By selecting Object and color matching

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, image-processing, crop

We are developing an app where we need to crop an image according to the selecting object area. User will draw a line and we need to select the object and crop it .This crop need to be like the app: [YourMoji](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/yourmoji-keyboard-create-custom/id981336914?mt=8)

So far we have tried to get the color of the pixels along the line and then comparing those with the color of every pixel in the image and making a path from it to clip the image. But the almost going no where.

[image: Croping image]

Is it possible through this way to crop an image or we are going in the wrong way? Can anyone provide a way to do this Or suggest a way to modify the way we have worked so far? 
Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you want is the image segmentation algorithm called [Graph Cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_cuts_in_computer_vision).

Here are two Github repositories, hope these would help:

- [GraphCut](https://github.com/agentlink/GraphCut)
- [GrabCutIOS](https://github.com/naver/grabcutIOS)

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I will try it out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly clued up on image manipulation, but the first algorithm that comes to mind is something like this:

- Take the average of the pixels in the line (as you have)

  - Since you appear to want faces, you might want to weight reds and blues over green. Not much green in faces of any skin tone.
- For each pixel, if the colour is within a given threshold outside of your selected average, remove it / make transparent.
- Perhaps the closer to the original line (or centroid), the less strict the threshold becomes.

I'd then provide the user with some tools for:

- Sensitivity: how large the threshold is
- Eraser: to remove parts of the image that your algorithm missed
- Paintbrush: to replace parts of the image that your algorithm incorrectly removed.